# javasctipt модули

Tags: javascript

Есть такой html (сокращенно, jquery подключен):

```
<body>
  <div>
    <span class="cl">Hello</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

пишу js код

```
(function(){
  var tmp = $('.cl').text()
  console.log(tmp)
  console.log('hell333333o');
}())
```

и в консоль выводит то что и написано

```
"Hello"
"hell333333o"
```

Как такое может быть или как оно работает, я думал что нужно передавать вот так:

```
(function(window, $){
      var tmp = $('.cl').text()
      console.log(tmp)
      console.log('hell333333o');
    }(window, $))
```

(я смотрю по примеру )

```
(function(window, google) {

  // map options
  var options = {
    center: {
      lat: 37.791350,
      lng: -122.435883
    },
    zoom: 10
  },
  element = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  // map
  map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

}(window, google));
```

Зачем здесь передают `window, google`? когда оно нужно?

Comment: Думаю, последний пример, это именно пример. Явно передали параметры в функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся соль в области видимости переменных в JS. Она просто напросто **функциональная**, а не блочная. Это означает, что **все** переменные объявленные именно в функции, например, в блоке `if(){}` и даже в блоке `for(){}`, всплывают вверх и становятся видимыми всему внутри функции. Благодаря этому вы можете использовать функцию (функция это ведь тоже объект), а потом только ее объявить. Это верно, когда Вы создаете переменные с помощью оператора `var`, с приходом ECMAScript 6 появился новый тип переменный, объявляемый с помощью `let`, там немного другие правила. Логично, что переменные объявленные во внешней функции видны и во внутренней. А объект `window` виден везде.

Замыкая (можно назвать этот прием *передачей замыкания*) таким образом, как у Вас написано, просто стараются сделать так, чтобы модуль был максимально независим от других. Вдруг у вас уже есть переменная `google`, а нужный `google` несет другое наименование, тогда Вы всегда можете передать в функцию именно то, что Вам необходимо. Или если вдруг вместо `window` вы хотите использовать окно `frame`, можно с легкостью его туда передать. Еще один яркий пример, это функция `$()`. Очень часто она является алиасом к jQuery, но еще часто этот символ используют как свою, пользовательскую функцию для поиска объектов по DOM. Тогда, для работы непосредственно с обектом `jQuery`, а не со своим объектом `$` в функции необходимо будет сделать уже вот так:

```
(function(window, $){
      var tmp = $('.cl').text()
      console.log(tmp)
      console.log('hell333333o');
 }(window, jQuery))
```

На таком принципе работы основаны все потуги JS программистов на создание приватных переменных. С приходом ECMAScript 6 в нашу жизнь, это (да и вообще ООП стиль программирования на JS) можно будет реализовывать немного проще, но за абстракцией будет всегда стоять именно такой смысл, да и когда это еще будет...

Comment: Спасибо что объяснили, разобрался зачем это нужно